# Understanding .I in data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I was playing around with `data.table` and I came across a distinction that I'm not sure I quite understand. Given the following dataset:

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(400)
DT <- data.table(x = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 20, TRUE), key = "x"); DT
```

Can you please explain to me the difference between the following expressions?

1) `DT[J("E"), .I]`

2) `DT[  , .I[x == "E"] ]`

3) `DT[x == "E", .I]`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
set.seed(400)
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(x = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 20, TRUE), key = "x"); DT
```

1)

```
DT[  , .I[x == "E"] ] # [1] 18 19 20
```

is a data.table where `.I` is a vector representing the row number of `E` in the ORIGINAL dataset `DT`

2)

```
DT[J("E")  , .I]   # [1] 1 2 3

DT["E"     , .I]   # [1] 1 2 3

DT[x == "E", .I]   # [1] 1 2 3
```

are all the same, producing a vector where `.I`s are vectors representing the row numbers of the `E`s in the NEW subsetted data