# Identify the original row numbers of filtered rows

Tags: r, data.table

I want to filter rows and store the original row number (of the source data) in a `data.table` column.

I know that `.I` has a syntax variant for that (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23586059/4468078) but this requires me to filter twice what I want to avoid:

```
DT <- mtcars
setDT(DT)
row.numbers <- DT[, .I[ gear > 4]]
# > row.numbers
# [1] 27 28 29 30 31
DT[row.numbers, .(row.numbers, gear)]
#    row.numbers gear
# 1:          27    5
# 2:          28    5
# 3:          29    5
# 4:          30    5
# 5:          31    5
```

If I use the normal `.I` syntax it returns the row number of the subset, not from the original data:

```
DT[gear > 4, .(.I, gear)]

   I gear
1: 1    5
2: 2    5
3: 3    5
4: 4    5
5: 5    5
```

Any ideas for an easier/optimized solution?

Comment: It may be possible, but it is my understanding that the data.table is subset in the `i` argument prior to any calculations in the `j` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit faster for the example in @RYoda's answer:

```
w = DT[x > LIMIT, which = TRUE ]
DT[w, c("x","y")][, w := w ]
```

To change the order of the columns in the result, `setcolorder` should work, taking almost no time.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit 2:** Added the `w2` variant of @Frank...

To supplement to accepted answer of @UweBlock I have done some benchmarks which I want to show here to share the results:

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)
# size: about 800 MB
DT <- data.table(x = sample(1000, 1E8, replace = TRUE), y = sample(1000, 1E8, replace = TRUE))
LIMIT <- 500

microbenchmark(row.filter = {
  row.numbers <- DT[, .I[x > LIMIT]]
  res <- DT[row.numbers, .(row.numbers, x, y)]
},
chaining = {
  res <- DT[, row.number := .I][x > LIMIT, .(row.number, x, y)]
},
w2 = {
  w = DT[x > LIMIT, which = TRUE ]
  DT[w, c("x","y")][, w := w ]
},
times = 20)
```

The result is:

```
Unit: seconds
       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 row.filter 2.039627 2.152165 2.290105 2.284775 2.381632 2.652203    20   b
   chaining 2.032791 2.272493 2.369759 2.359630 2.472028 2.777191    20   b
         w2 1.104414 1.194826 1.274428 1.257893 1.311050 1.557225    20  a
```

**Edit 1:** To compare the impact of filter selectivity:

For `LIMIT <- 100`:

```
Unit: seconds
       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 row.filter 3.254134 3.638193 4.053991 3.865599 4.432278 5.337939    20   b
   chaining 3.005504 3.874443 4.116179 4.069974 4.391666 4.994020    20   b
         w2 1.289617 1.588608 1.965523 1.962185 2.294457 2.859689    20  a
```

And for `LIMIT <- 900`:

```
Unit: milliseconds
       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
 row.filter 900.9504 905.0694 914.9406 907.5211 916.2071  964.6856    20  b 
   chaining 927.1630 932.0981 965.8222 970.9336 981.5885 1030.6396    20   c
         w2 607.0091 609.8028 620.5582 612.0490 615.2337  669.9706    20 a
```

Comment: Nice, especially to check for filter selectivity. It seems, that for less rows (shorter `row.number` vector, filtering with `x > 900`) the `row.filter` approach is about 1.5% faster while for a longer `row.number` vectors, `chaining` is about 0.5% faster.

Comment: Here's another benchmark, though I didn't have the patience to run it more than 3x: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/38334338#38334338

Comment: And... `w2 = {
      w = DT[x > th, which = TRUE ];
      DT[w, c("x","y")][, w := w ]
    }` is proving the fastest for me. (Could use `setcolorder` on the result if you want row numbers first.)

Comment: I am updating the benchmark and try to understand why it is faster (using `which`, different chaining order?)

Comment: @Frank If you post an answer I will change my vote (sorry Uwe, I was too fast)

Comment: I'm not really sure why it's faster. Creating the intermediate object, `w`, should be slow in some cases, I guess.

Comment: I was pretty sure, @Frank would come up with an even better/faster `data.table` solution :-) So, no worries.

Answer (score 2):

#### Why another benchmark?

1. Frank mentioned in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45332137/identify-the-original-row-numbers-of-filtered-rows/45332285#comment77633690_45332285) that there might be a speed up by switching from `.(rn, gear)` to `c("rn", "gear")` but didn't benchmark that separately.
2. In [R yoda's benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45332781/3817004), the sample data are of type *integer* but `LIMIT <- 500` is of type *double*. `data.table` occasionally warns about type conversions so I wonder what effect on performance the type conversion may have in this case.

#### What to benchmark?

Up to now, 3 answers have been provided which make up five code variants:

- [R Yoda's *row.filter* approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45332137/3817004)
- [Uwe's *chaining* approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45332285/3817004) in two variants: with non-standard evaluation (NSE) and, by Frank's suggestion, with standard evaluation (SE)
- [Frank's approach using *which*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45335841/3817004) also in two variants: SE as posted by Frank and NSE for a speed comparison.

Unfortunately, I couldn't get the *row.filter* to work in a SE version.

#### Which parameters are used?

- Problem size (number of rows): 10<sup>2</sup>, 10<sup>3</sup>, ..., 10<sup>8</sup>
- Different values for `LIMIT`: 100, 500, 900
- Type of `LIMIT`: *integer*, *double* to test the effect of type conversion

The number of repetitions is computed from the problem size with a minimum of 3 runs and a maximum of 100 runs.

#### Results

Type conversion does cost about 4% (median) to 9% (mean) of performance. So it  *does matter* if you write `LIMIT <- 500` or `LIMIT <- 500L` using `L` to indicate an integer constant.

[image]

The performance penalty for using non-standard evaluation is much higher: NSE needs on average more than 50% more time than SE - for both approaches.
(Note that the chart below only shows results for type *integer*)

[image]

The chart below for limit *500* and type *integer* indicates that the SE variants are faster than their NSE counterparts for all problem sizes. Interestingly, *chaining_se* seems to have a slight advantage over *which_se* for smaller problem sizes up to 5000 rows while for problem sizes above 5 M rows *which_se* is clearly faster.

[image]

By request, here is a table showing the timings in ms for above chart:

```
dcast(bm_med[limit == 500L & type == "int"][
  , expr := forcats::fct_reorder(factor(expr), -time)],
  expr ~ n_rows, fun.aggregate = function(x) max(x/1E6), value.var = "time")
```

> ```
>            expr       100      1000     10000    1e+05    1e+06    1e+07    1e+08
> 1: chaining_nse 0.8189745 0.8493695 1.0115405 2.870750 22.34469 441.1621 2671.179
> 2:   row.filter 0.7693225 0.7972635 0.9622665 2.677807 21.30861 247.3984 2677.495
> 3:    which_nse 0.8486145 0.8690035 1.0117295 2.620980 18.39406 219.0794 2341.990
> 4:  chaining_se 0.5299360 0.5582545 0.6454755 1.700626 12.48982 166.0164 2049.904
> 5:     which_se 0.5894045 0.6114935 0.7040005 1.624166 13.00125 130.0718 1289.050
> ```

#### Benchmark code

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)
run_bm <- function(n_rows, limit = 500L, type = "int") {
  set.seed(1234L)
  DT <- data.table(x = sample(1000, n_rows, replace = TRUE), 
                   y = sample(1000, n_rows, replace = TRUE))
  LIMIT <- switch(type,
                  int = as.integer(limit),
                  dbl = as.double(limit))
  times <- round(scales::squish(sqrt(1E8 / n_rows) , c(3L, 100L)))
  cat("Start run:", n_rows, limit, type, times, "\n")
  microbenchmark(row.filter = {
    row.numbers <- DT[, .I[x > LIMIT]]
    DT[row.numbers, .(row.numbers, x, y)]
  },
  chaining_nse = {
    DT[, row.number := .I][x > LIMIT, .(row.number, x, y)]
  },
  chaining_se = {
    DT[, row.number := .I][x > LIMIT, c("row.number", "x", "y")]
  },
  which_nse = {
    row.numbers <- DT[x > LIMIT, which = TRUE ]
    DT[row.numbers, .(x, y)][, row.numbers := row.numbers ][]
  },
  which_se = {
    row.numbers <- DT[x > LIMIT, which = TRUE ]
    DT[row.numbers, c("x", "y")][, row.numbers := row.numbers][]
  },
  times = times)
}
# parameter
bm_par <- CJ(n_rows = 10^seq(2L, 8L, 1L), 
             limit = seq(100L, 900L, 400L), 
             type = c("int", "dbl"))
# run the benchmarks
bm_raw <- bm_par[, run_bm(n_rows, limit, type), by = .(n_rows, limit, type)]
# aggregate results
bm_med <- bm_raw[, .(time = median(time)), by = .(n_rows, limit, type, expr)]
```

#### Graphics code

```
library(ggplot2)

# chart 1
ggplot(
  dcast(bm_med, n_rows + limit + expr ~ type, value.var = "time")[
    , ratio := dbl / int - 1.0] #[limit == 500L]
) + 
  aes(n_rows, ratio, colour = expr) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(limit ~ expr) + 
  scale_x_log10(labels = function(x) scales::math_format()(log10(x))) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-0.1, 0.5)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  theme_bw() +
  ggtitle("Performance loss due to type conversion") +
  ylab("Relative computing time dbl vs int") + 
  xlab("Number of rows (log scale)")
ggsave("p2.png")

# chart 2
ggplot(
  dcast(bm_med[, c("code", "eval") := tstrsplit(expr, "_")][!is.na(eval)], 
        n_rows + limit + type + code ~ eval, value.var = "time")[
          , ratio := nse / se - 1.0][type == "int"]
) + 
  aes(n_rows, ratio, colour = code) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(limit  + type ~ code) + 
  scale_x_log10(labels = function(x) scales::math_format()(log10(x))) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  theme_bw() +
  ggtitle("Performance loss due to non standard evaluation") +
  ylab("Relative computing time NSE vs SE") + 
  xlab("Number of rows (log scale)")
ggsave("p3.png")

# chart 3
ggplot(bm_med[limit == 500L][type == "int"]) + 
  aes(n_rows, time/1E6, colour = expr) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE) + 
  facet_grid(limit ~ type) +
  facet_grid(type ~ limit) +
  scale_x_log10(labels = function(x) scales::math_format()(log10(x))) +
  scale_y_log10(labels = function(x) scales::math_format()(log10(x))) +
  theme_bw() +
  ggtitle("Benchmark results (log-log scale)") +
  ylab("Computing time in ms (log scale)") + 
  xlab("Number of rows (log scale)")
ggsave("p1.png")
```

Comment: WOW! Regarding NSE: For details see http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html

Comment: @RYoda Thank you for supplementing the link! Another good read might be the [vignette to Hadley's `lazyeval` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lazyeval/vignettes/lazyeval.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can add a column of row numbers before filtering:

```
library(data.table)
data.table(mtcars)[, rn := .I][gear > 4, .(rn, gear)]
```

> ```
>    rn gear
> 1: 27    5
> 2: 28    5
> 3: 29    5
> 4: 30    5
> 5: 31    5
> ```

#### Benchmarking

Just a quick benchmark with the `mtcars` data set (32 rows) which is far to small but the focus here is on overhead.

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  copy = DT <- data.table(mtcars),
  ryoda = {
    DT <- data.table(mtcars)
    row.numbers <- DT[, .I[ gear > 4]]
    DT[row.numbers, .(row.numbers, gear)]
  },
  uwe = {
    DT <- data.table(mtcars)
    DT[, rn := .I][gear > 4, .(rn, gear)]
  },
  times = 1000L
)
```

> ```
> Unit: microseconds
>   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
>   copy  691.710  727.192  803.235  749.385  785.428 15989.293  1000 a  
>  ryoda 1821.869 1883.479 2001.653 1930.213 2011.124  6650.497  1000  b 
>    uwe 1860.288 1934.191 2053.004 1987.927 2077.370  5908.892  1000   c
> ```

Note that each benchmark run is started with a fresh copy of DT because one of the codes is modifying `DT` in place (using `:=`).

Here, it seems that there is a penalty of 50 to 60 microseconds with chaining for the tiny 32 rows sample data set. [R Yoda's benchmark results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45332781/3817004) with a large data set of 800 M rows show differences of about 1% in both directions depending on the number of filtered rows, i.e., the length of `row.numbers`.

Comment: Yes, chaining is an option, but may cost performance too (even though it looks minor since only a new column/vector is appended). But the filtering is done only once, good answer!

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. I'm aware that piping (`%>%`) may cost performance but I  wasn't aware that chaining may cost performance as well (I trust that the `data.table` guys are pretty much focused on efficiency). Do you have an example of this?

Comment: Lucky strike, I have found it again: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Memory-usage-of-data-table-chaining-td4703587.html (it is related to memory usage, but memory usage may cost performance)

Comment: Thank you very much  for the link. I wonder how this would be answered today, 2 and a half years and a lot of optimisations of `data.table` later.

Comment: Absolutely right and would be worth a new SO question since @arun was participating in the linked discussion. I thought there is already a SO question, answer or comment to brought me to this link but I don't find it ATM.

Comment: Chaining doesn't cost you in this case, since you don't "materialize" a new table after the first step, instead just adding by reference to an existing table, right? I guess yours might speed up by switching from `.(rn, gear)` to `c("rn", "gear")` but didn't benchmark that separately.

Comment: @Frank I've added another [benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45347181/3817004) comparing both variants. It's more than 50% speed gain!